# Error ruby version When i'm running bundle install in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, rvm, jekyll, bundler, ubuntu-16.04

I have reinstalled and updated my Ubuntu to 16.04, so now i have installed RVM for use Jekyll, but i have a problem when run bundle install of gemfile.

```
$ bundle install
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  
Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

$ rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.2.0 (found in /home/kedinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0)
```

No running because this `2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.0` why? if i have using ruby-2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have both RVM and rbenv installed, and they are probably in conflict. Since they do more or less the same things, it should be safe to get rid of one of them. It means the rbenv installation of ruby is broken.

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rbenv
```

Try installing [Ruby like this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04)